# Python recursion on heap memory

Tags: python, heap-memory, stack-memory

Is there any good methods to place recursion stack on heap to prevent stack overflowing?

Of course, there is method to store own stack and place there function's variables (frame) and just  simulate recursion, and, by all appearances, I'm looking for something like decorator, which will do it automatically.

Comment: 'pervert'? really? or did you mean 'prevent'?

Comment: Change it to tail recursion. You can either maintain constant space, or you end up explicitly maintaining the stack on heap.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few options here.

1. Use stackless Python, as the name would suggest it doesn't have this problem.
2. Build your own stack instead of using recursion
3. **NOT RECOMMENDED** Increase the recursion limit https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit

Comment: 1. This is the exactly that I need, but CPython required.
2. I mentioned about this in my question. It's a solution, but, in fact, I'm looking for something like syntax sugar for this.
3. Anyway, I am limited by the system stack size, and want to be limited to the size of the heap

Comment: In that case rewriting the code or changing the recursion limit are your options.

Comment: I tried stackless but I'm still getting a `RecursionError`. Even using `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)`, it doesn't seem to go above 1000 calls.